# Codeigniter do not show name attribute to user

Tags: jquery, html, codeigniter

If a user will view page source, he will see the following line. Could you help me to hide name attribute please.

```
<button name="25" type="button" class="rate">Vote Up</button>
```

Here is my view code:

```
<?php 

  $data = array(
    'name' => $id,
    'class' => 'rate',    
    'content' => 'Vote Up'    
    );
   echo form_button($data);

   ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot hide the name attribute. It is how the browser knows what its handing back. It would be similar to handing back a paper form I and scratching out all the field headers for the form itself, the reader would have no idea what each field is. This is not a codeigniter feature, This is a HTML rule.